# Encuentre el mayor elemento contiguo

Tags: python

Dado un arreglo, imprima el mayor elemento contiguo (MEC) para cada elemento. El mayor elemento contiguo (MEC) para un elemento x es el primer mayor elemento de la derecha de x en un arreglo. Los elementos para los cuales no existe el mayor elemento contiguo, asigne como mayor elemento el valor -1.

Sírvase de estos ejemplos:

1. Para cualquier arreglo, el elemento de más a la derecha siempre tiene como mayor elemento contigo a -1.
2. Para cualquier arreglo ordenado de forma descendente, todos los elementos tienen como mayor elemento contiguo a -1.
3. Para el arreglo de entrada [4, 5, 2, 25], los mayores elementos contiguos para cada elemento son los siguientes:

   > ```
   > Elemento       MEC
   >    4      -->   5;
   >    5      -->   25;
   >    2      -->   25;
   >    25     -->   -1;
   > ```
4. Para el arreglo de entrada [13,7,6,12], los mayores elementos contiguos para cada elemento son los siguientes:

   > ```
   >  Elemento        MEC
   >   13      -->    -1;
   >   7       -->     12;
   >   6       -->     12;
   >   12      -->     -1;
   > ```

Su solución deberá entregarse usando dos métodos:

1. El método #1 (Usando Arreglos)
2. El método #2 (Usando Pilas)

Tengo esto:

```
lista =  [4, 5, 2, 25]
print "Los valores de la lista son: ",lista

n=input("Busque el elemento contiguo de la lista: ")


a=lista[0]
b=lista[1]
c=lista[2]
d=lista[3]

if n==a:
  if a<b:
    print"Contiguo de: ",n," es: ", b

if n==b:
  if b<c:
    print"Contiguo de: ",n," es: ", c
  else:
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? ¿Qué dificultades te has encontrado? ¿Has tenido algún error? ¿Tienes algo de código que podamos mirar?

Comment: Bienvenido, mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta y que sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funciona el sitio. Tu pregunta tal como está formulada entra en la categoría "hagan mi tarea", que no es bien recibida por la comunidad. Te sugiero que intentes resolver el ejercicio planteado y eventualmente consultes en el sitio a medida que vayas encontrándote con dificultades.

Comment: Tu título menciona el lenguaje C++, pero una de las etiquetas es Python (?)

Answer (score 0):

Dado que esta pregunta tiene pinta de ser tarea de un curso de programación, voy a ayudarte con una respuesta que posiblemente no te acepten "todavía", aunque lo único medio avanzado es el uso de filter.

```
for i,value in enumerate(your_list):
    # Get all larger numbers to the right
    possible_numbers = list(filter(lambda x:x>val, your_list[i+1:]))
    if possible_numbers:
        # Show the closest number larger than value
        print(possible_numbers[0])
    else:
        print(-1)
```